# if I have lists for the values in a dictionary, can I perform a conditional zip on these value lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have the following dict that I created :

```
dct = {'T': [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], 'B': [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], 'J': [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], 'K': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Note that each value is either a single list or multiple lists. I am trying to figure out if I can do a conditional zip on the value lists for each key (or some alternative solution that gives me my desired output). The condition is that I only want the value lists to zip together for a given key if the 1s on consecutive value lists are within a distance of 2 index values from each other.

The final output I want from this input dict should look like this:

```
zp_dict = {'T': [2, 1, 0, 1, 0], 'B': [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0]], 'J': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'K': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Notice that the value lists for 'T' and 'J' should be zipped together because the non-zero values are no more than 2 indices apart, but the value lists for 'B' should be kept separate because the non-zero values are 3 indices apart, and the 'K' value list should be left alone.

To illustrate what I'm trying to do, consider the following code that almost does what I want to do, but without the condition:

```
zp_dict = {}

for k, v in dct.items():

    zp_dict[k] = [sum(x) for x in zip(*v)]
```

This produces the following new dict, which is wrong for key 'B':

```
zp_dict = { 'T': [2, 1, 0, 1, 0], 'B': [0, 1, 0, 0, 1], 'J': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'K': [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

Comment: i dont think the downvotes are necessary ... he clearly has made an effort ... just he hasnt quite explained the criteria in any way that I for one can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This technically achieves the result you are asking for. However, I am assuming you want everything to be added together if at least 2 of the lists have numbers within 2 indexes of each other. For example `[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]` would result in `[1, 1, 0, 0, 1]` **NOT** `[[1, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]` despite the last list having its number more than 2 indexes away from any other list.

The code sums the lists together, then finds how far apart the first 2 non-zero number are. If they are <= 2 indexes apart, then the summed list is added to `zp_dict`, else the list of lists (`v`) remains unchanged, and added to the `zp_dict`

The code is on [OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/Hke7TCeZ7), if you want to tinker with it

**Note:** I assumed `'K'` in the `dct` you provided had a typo, in that it was supposed to be a list within a list (like the others) - if not, `sum(x) for x in zip(*v)` would break. If not, it doesn't take much to fix - just validate the number of lists in `v`.

```
dct = {
    'T': [[1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]], 
    'B': [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], 
    'J': [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], 
    'K': [[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]
}

zp_dict = {}

for k, v in dct.items():
    sum_list = [sum(x) for x in zip(*v)]
    first_non_zero = next((i for i, n in enumerate(sum_list) if n), 0)
    second_non_zero = next((i for i, n in enumerate(sum_list[first_non_zero+1:]) if n), 0)
    zp_dict[k] = sum_list if second_non_zero < 2 else v

print(zp_dict)
>>{'T': [2, 1, 0, 1, 0], 'B': [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]], 'J': [0, 0, 1, 0, 1], 'K',: [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]}
```

**EDIT:**
You can also add if statements (with functions inline), if that is what you were looking for.

```
zp_dict[k] = [sum(x) for x in zip(*v) if conditionTest(v)]
```

If the `conditionTest` returns `True`, it would add the lists together. Although if you were fine with adding functions, I would clean it up and just add the for loop into the function:

```
zp_dict[k] = sumFunction(v)
```